# incorporating PHP into javascript media queries

Tags: javascript, php

I have a JS file that I only want loaded at a certain screen size.

I know I can use:

```
if (screen.width >= 600) {

}
```

but I need to incorporate the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>-child/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is your problem ?

Comment: You're mixing server side concepts with client side ones. Re-think it.

Comment: Ok.. Let me rephrase the question:

How can I load a javascript file only at a certain screen size (For instance only load on desktop version, not mobile).

The URL of the file needs to contain a dynamic URL: get_template_directory_uri();

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[jQuery getScript](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) seems like it should do the job for you.

Something like this should work:

```
if (screen.width >= 600) {
    $.getScript( "<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>-child/js/jquery.slimscroll.min.js", function( data, textStatus, jqxhr ) {
        console.log( data ); // Data returned
        console.log( textStatus ); // Success
        console.log( jqxhr.status ); // 200
        console.log( "Load was performed." );
    });
}
```

Comment: Fantastic. I'll give this a shot.